# overloading operator< for pointers to class object

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, operator-overloading

I'm trying to figure out how to implement an operator< overload for an Item Pointer class that points to an Item class object. It is part of a program that stores pointers to Items in an STL set. The overload is necessary for an ordered STL set (alphabetical by title).  I know the code is wrong for the ItemPtr overload below. I thought I could dereference the pointer to get at the actual item, but I don't know how to implement this. I hope I'm on the right track. I appreciate any pointers (no pun intended) anyone can share.

```
bool operator<(const Item& i1, const Item& i2)
{
    const char* str1 = i1.getTitle().c_str();
    const char* str2 = i2.getTitle().c_str();
    return strcmp(str1, str2);
}

bool operator<(const ItemPtr& ip1, const ItemPtr& ip2)
{
    const Item& i1 = *ip1;
    const Item& i2 = *ip2;
    return i1 < i2;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not simply `return ItemPtr1->getTitle() < ItemPtr2->getTitle()`?

Comment: Are these friend functions or class functions?

Comment: Is the question "How do you write a deference operation"?

Comment: Is `ItemPtr` always storing a pointer to `Item`? Or may be pointing to anything (`nullptr`)?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method, assuming you guarantee there are no invalid pointers in the `set` and `getTitle()` is `const`:

```
bool operator<(const ItemPtr& ip1, const ItemPtr& ip2)
{
  return ip1->getTitle() < ip2->getTitle();
}
```

I would caution however that needing to do this kind of thing triggers my sense that there is something possibly wrong with your design.  In particular, why are you storing pointers-to-`Item` in your `set`, rather than just the `Item` itself?  Is this really needed?

Comment: I will try that, thanks! I agree that the design is strange — it is dictated by an assignment which is structured to store Item pointers in various sets which are then stored in a map containing the sets that are indexed according to keywords. I don't exactly understand why it is set up this way — it has something to do with const correctness, as all the items are set up to be constant items with constant pointers. It is really throwing me for a loop to implement — Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The wrong thing in your implementation is not comparing `ItemPtr`s, but comparing `Item`s: `strcmp()` will return a not zero value when `str1` and `str2` are different, and returning non-zero value means `true`. You cannot get ordered elements if `a < b` and `b < a` at the same time. Because `ItemPtr` comparison is implemented as function of `Item` comparison, it will have the same problem.

The solution given by John Dibling is easy and right if you're sure `ItemPtr` always contains a valid `Item` reference:

```
bool operator<(const ItemPtr& ip1, const ItemPtr& ip2)
{
    return ip1->getTitle() < ip2->getTitle();
}
```

If you need to compare `Item`s anyway:

```
bool operator<(const Item& i1, const Item& i2)
{
    return i1.getTitle() < i2.getTitle();
}
bool operator<(const ItemPtr& ip1, const ItemPtr& ip2)
{
    return *i1 < *i2;
}
```

If you cannot assume `ItemPtr` store a valid reference, you will have to check that case. (But probably you can assume that).